# How to Run Expo in Background and when App is Terminated?

Tags: expo

I am trying to add a functionality to my app in expo that allows it to run in the background and when it is terminated. I need it to monitor a users location over time even when the app is terminated. I also am fine with solutions that only work on android. Any help is appreciated.